# Conjugate to σ in the alternating group

Tags: group-theory

There is $S_7$ and the subgroup $\langle σ\rangle = \{(1 \; 2\; 3\; 4 \; 5)^i | i \in \mathbb Z\}$ of $S_7$ generated by $σ = (1 \; 2\; 3\; 4 \; 5)$

Then, how many elements are conjugate to σ in $A_7$?

The order of σ is 5 and well.. I know that conjugation of symmetric group(preserve the cycle type) but how to find the number of elements?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have to determine here is whether the conjugacy class in $S_n$ of elements of this cycle type is a single class in $A_n$ or whether it splits into two classes in $A_n$.

Comment: Remember, in a general finite group $G,$ the number of conjugates of $x$ is $[G:C_{G}(x)].$

Comment: I'm not sure the answer was right though.. thank you both for your help

Comment: The answer is $504$.

Answer (score -1):

The cycle decomposition of the given permutation $\sigma=(1,2,3,4,5)(6)(7)$ contains one $5$-cycle and two fixed points ($1$-cycles).  By the splitting criterion [[1](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group#In_terms_of_cycle_decompositions),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404656/splitting-of-conjugacy-class-in-alternating-group)], because the cycle lengths $5$, $1$, and $1$ are not ***distinct* odd numbers** (there are two $1$-cycles in $\sigma$), the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ does NOT split when restricted to $A_{7}$ from $S_{7}$.

---

The process is: (hover to view)

> There are ${7\choose 5}\cdot4!=504$ [[3](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_determines_conjugacy_class#For_a_finite_set)] conjugates of $\sigma$ in $S_{7}$.
>  By the splitting criterion, because the cycle lengths of $\sigma$ (namely $5$, $1$, and $1$) are not distinct odd numbers, the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ does not split.  So there are exactly $504$ conjugates of $\sigma$ in $A_{7}$.