# How to find the conjugacy classes of the alternating group $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I am a new user and I don’t know how to use Latex, so I apologize for my text first.
I have two questions.

1:
I know that the conjugate of a cycle in $S_n$ will not change its cycle type. And I know the converse is also true, i.e. all the cycle with same cycle type consists of a conjugacy class. But I don’t know how to prove this converse. Is there anyone can help me with this?

2:
As above, we can write down all the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ easily since we just need to find all the types of cycle, which exactly corresponds to all the partitions of `1, 2, ..., n`.
The question is that how we find all the conjugacy classes of $A_n$? The method in dealing with $S_n$ doesn’t work now, since there always are two different cycles with the same cycle type, but they are conjugated by a odd cycle. I think about this for a time, but I can’t find a way to formulate it.
So is there someone can help me with this?

Appreciate so much :)

*Link*

Another detailed proof see: [Splitting of conjugacy class in alternating group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404656/507382) , as Ethan Bolker quotes.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404656/splitting-of-conjugacy-class-in-alternating-group and https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you so much. It’s helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be an even permutation. If there is an odd permutation
commuting with $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ has the same conjugacy class
in $A_n$ as in $S_n$. Otherwise the centraliser of $\sigma$ in $S_n$
is a subgroup of $A_n$ and the conjugacy class of $\sigma$ in $S_n$
splits into two classes in $A_n$.

If $\sigma$ has a cycle of even length, then that's an odd permutation
centralising $\sigma$. If $\sigma$ has two cycles of the same odd
length $k$, then there is an involution swapping these two cycles, and
centralising $\sigma$. This involution has $k$ two-cycles and
so is an odd permutation.

The only remaining possibility is if the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$
consists of cycles of distinct odd lengths. In this case the
centraliser of $\sigma$ is generated by these cycles and so is
contained in $A_n$. These are the conjugacy classes of $S_n$
that split into two classes in $A_n$.

Comment: I can follow your proof now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is find the conjugacy classes of the following elements and use symmetry:

$e$

$(1,2)(3,4)$

$(1,2,3)$

We know that the cycle representation of $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ is the same of $\tau$ but changing every element by its image under $\sigma$.
/

---

the conjugacy class of $e$ is clear.

---

The conjugacy class of $(1,2,3)$ has size $4$ because the centralizer of $(1,2,3)$ is just its own powers.

---

The conjugacy class of $(1,2)(3,4)$ has size $3$ because the centralizer of $(1,2)(3,4)$ has size $4$ because it is generated by  $(1,3)(2,4)$ and $(1,2)(3,4)$.

Therefore the $3$-cycles are split into two and the double $2$-cycles remain a conjugacy class.

Comment: Could you explain more detail about the last two sections? How can we get the size of conjugacy from its centralizer? And how we determine if split the 3-cycles or 2-cycles based on the size of their conjugacy respectively? Thanks.

Comment: In general if one has a group action $G\rightarrow X$ then the size of the orbit of $x$ is the order of $G$ divided by the order of the stabilizer of $x$. In this case $G$ acts over itself via conjugation and the stabilizer of $g$ is its centralizer.

Comment: Yes I know this result, which is the orbit-stabilizer theorem. So you assume the order of $G$ is 12 here? And I don’t know how we determine if split the cycle types yet. Could you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: the order of $A_4$ is $12$.

Comment: Yes. But I wanna know the case for $A_n$. The case for n should be motivated by your case. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you understand lord sharks solution?

Comment: Yes I can follow most of the proof. But I still have some small detailed problems with his proof. I will check it tomorrow. If I still can’t follow, I will ask him or you. Thank you two. :)

Comment: I can understand his proof now, thank you so much.