# Permutations that conjugate in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Find two permutations that conjugate in $S_5$, but not in $A_5$.

I can't understand why is it possible - in order for two permutations to conjugate, they must have the same cycle structure.

If two permutations are conjugate in $S_5$, this means they have the same cycle structure, and therefore will have the same structure in $A_5$, and will be still conjugate in $A_5$...

What am I missing?

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464582/11619). I think we have even better threads, but that came up first in my search.

Comment: What's happening is that the conjugacy class of $S_n$ may or may not split in two conjugacy classes in $A_n$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260330/11619).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/306553/11619) the corresponding exercise in Dummit & Foote is discussed. I won't pick a dupe target because my search is biased by my own history. But I suspect others explained this earlier and better and I simply can't find a link to those threads quickly.

Comment: Just for you to think concretely: Are the $3$-cycles $(1\,2\,3)$ and $(1\,3\,2)$ conjugate in $A_3$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin In general, I'm not sure how can I prove that something does not conjugate, rather than looking at the cycle structure or trying all possiblities, which obviously isn't a good idea.

Comment: You might think about orbits and stabilizers ... but for the $A_3$ question it should be immediate.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen In the first link you gave here, they show $(12345)$ and $(21345)$ as examples. But they don't show that for every $ \sigma \in A_5$ those two permutations don't conjugate, but only for specific permutations...

Comment: ChikChak, my favorite way of seeing that no permutation from $A_5$ will work is the following. There are $24$ 5-cycles in $S_5$. As $|S_5|=120$ we see that the centralizer of a 5-cycle has order $120/24=5$. But a 5-cycle is obviously centralized by its powers. So if $\alpha\in S_5$ is a 5-cycle, then $C_{S_5}(\alpha)=\langle \alpha\rangle$. Assume that $\beta$ is some other 5-cycle, and $\gamma\beta\gamma^{-1}=\alpha$, and $\delta\beta\delta^{-1}=\alpha$,

Comment: (cont'd) Then $\gamma\delta^{-1}$ commutes with $\beta$. Putting the pieces together it follows that $\gamma\delta^{-1}$ must be a power of $\beta$, say $\gamma=\beta^i\delta$. But as a 5-cycle $\beta^i$ is even. So if $\gamma$ is odd so is $\delta$. In other words, either all the permutations that take $\beta$ to $\alpha$ are even, or they are all odd.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen So basically, every two $5$-cycle in $S_5$ cannot conjuagte in $A_5$?

Comment: No. I didn¨t say that! If you conjugate a 5-cycle by any even  permutation you still get another 5-cycle. In fact $C_{A_5}(\alpha)=C_{S_5}(\alpha)\simeq C_5$. So the conjugacy class of $\alpha$ in $A_5$ has $60/5=12$ elements. In other words the class of 24 splits into two classes of 12.

Comment: I said that if some two 5-cycles are gotten from each other by conjugation, then the parity of that conjugating element is fixed. Because one of the conjugating permutations that takes $(12345)$ to $(21345)$ is odd, they all are. That's what the argument was trying to justify.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Why does the centralizer of $5$-cycle has order $120/24$?

Comment: Are you familiar with [the orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside's_lemma)? Or how the size of the centralizer determines the size of  a conjugacy class?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, being conjugate in $S_5$ is equivalent to having the same cycle structure.  But this is not true in $A_5$.  Two permutations that are conjugate in $A_5$ will have the same cycle structure, but the converse is not necessarily true.  $x,y \in A_5$ and $y=gxg^{-1}$ where $g \in S_5 \backslash A_5$ then it implies $x$ and $y$ are conjugate in $S^5$ but they might not be conjugate in $A^5$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ is a $5$-cycle in $S_5$ then the permutations in $S_5$
which commute with it are the powers of $\alpha$ which are all even.
If $\beta$ is an odd permutation, and $\alpha'=\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$
then $\alpha'$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$ in $S_5$ but not in $A_5$.
For if $\alpha'=\beta'\alpha\beta'^{-1}$ for $\beta'\in A_5$ then
$\beta^{-1}\beta'$ commutes with $\alpha$, so lies in $A_5$.
That forces $\beta\in A_5$, a contradiction.

I like this geometric picture. $A_5$ is isomorphic to the
rotation group of the regular icosahedron. That has a rotation
of order $5$ with angle $2\pi/5$. Its square is a rotation of
order $5$ with angle $4\pi/5$. These two rotations cannot be conjugate;
these correspond to non-conjugate $5$-cycles in $A_5$.

Comment: Therefore, $5$-cycles can never conjugate on $A_5$?